# Why Does the App crashes on Low Device Memory?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am particularly new to iOS & still quite distant from the basic Concepts.

I read in iOS books & forums that the application crashes due to low memory but why does it crash?
It would be helpful if someone could throw some light.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

iOS Devices Use virtual memory with Paging . As it is a Mobile device and there is no Extensible memory or pretty 
large Memory available (Like Hard drives) , so the availability of the pages is limited by various factors such as the number of applications open , Allocations by different applications , etc. Moreover , some on-board applications will always keep using some pages even when they are in dormant state such as safari , i-tunes , messaging etc.
So , essentially with number of application active , the number of pages your application can use gets diminished further.

So , your application will crash in cases when the rate of allocation by your application is exceeding the rate at which pages are being freed by other Applications.

OS only frees up read-only data from the memory while writable data is not freed-up .When the writable data crosses a certain threshold , the OS asks the application to free memory.Unable to free the memory leads to the crash.

[Memory Allocations Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/Articles/MemoryAlloc.html)

Comment: The term "paging" commonly refers to swapping main memory in and out to disk. iOS does not do this by default (though applications are free to use mapped memory which uses the same concept).

Comment: iOS uses VM Manager or Virtual memory manager helping to create logical addresses for different processes and dividing it into small chunks called pages. The Page Table maintains a track of it , that's why referred as paging

Comment: The number of pages available is not related to the physical memory available. Fwiw, you can allocate the whole 32bit virtual address space (minus the upper 1gig that is reserved for the kernel) without any problem.

Comment: Also, the OS doesn't free ANY memory that is used. It sounds like you got confused over what a dirty page is and what is not (ie writing to a page makes it become a dirty page that is not purged. That doesn't mean that memory you only read from is ever purged)

Comment: As mentioned by Nikolai , paging is just swapping main memory in & out of disk , but in iOS there is no paging out , but just paging in .Just edited 2 make It clearer

Answer (score 3):

It does not really crash. Apps get terminated by the kernel if they do not free enough memory after a notification.

To make this transparent a crash report is written which contains the specifics about the current situation. To the user it looks like the application crashed, as it just suddenly disappears.

Comment: I'm setting urlcache's memory to 200mb and setting the disk space to 1mb. Then I download an image. Force quit the app, launch the app again by tapping it, but it immediately crashes **without** any error in the debugger. Why?

Answer (score 2):

The devices don’t have much memory and if you are piggy with memory, you are looking for trouble

iOS have good memory tool called ARC. Please read the full documentation [here](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html)

Comment: Small note: ARC can only help reducing memory leaks but doesn't help if the app is allocating too much memory, e.g. by loading many huge images at once. So it can't help in the situation described in the above question. But it still helps making memory management easier :)

Answer (score 0):

[I've been burned before in my own apps when loading table views consisting of nothing but UIImages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12773074/received-memory-warning-on-setimage/12773139#12773139), which might look like tiny thumbnails in the table but end up being full resolution (and lots of memory) objects behind the scenes.

You need to be careful when working with objects that can be potential memory hogs.

But take heart, Apple provides tools like Xcode Instruments you can use to profile your app's memory performance.