# iOS easier way to resize image

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to resize an image on a background thread and the app always crashes after a few low memory warnings. How can I rewrite the code below to fix this?

```
float max = 1024*1024;
NSData *pngData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(setImage);

while ([pngData length] > max) {
    pngData = nil;
    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(setImage.size.width*.9, setImage.size.height *.9);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
    image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    NSLog(@"scale: %f", (1024.0*1024.0)/((float)[pngData length]));
    pngData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
}

NSLog(@"image length: %i",[pngData length]);
[pngData writeToFile:imageLocation atomically:YES];
```

I have already tried doing this by calculating the scale and replace the .9 in the code with a scale value

```
float scale = (max)/((float)[pngData length]);
CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(setImage.size.width*scale, setImage.size.height *scale);
```

This made the image too small.

The end goal is to take an image from the camera and save it to disk. I originally had to resize the image because I was getting a "Low Memory warning" when loading the image.

Comment: look at the accepted answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12773074/received-memory-warning-on-setimage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code causes an infinite loop and creates images until you run out of memory. Try something like this to fix the infinite loop:

```
float max = 1024*1024;
NSData *pngData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(setImage);
CGSize newSize = setImage.size;

while ([pngData length] > max) {
    newSize = CGSizeMake(newSize.width * 0.9, newSize.height * 0.9);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
    [setImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    NSLog(@"scale: %f", (1024.0*1024.0)/((float)[pngData length]));
    pngData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    image = nil;
}

NSLog(@"image length: %i",[pngData length]);
[pngData writeToFile:imageLocation atomically:YES];
```

Comment: This works better. The app does not crash but I still get a low memory warning.

Comment: That's fine. A low memory warning does not necessarily mean there is a problem with your app as long as memory is properly cleaned up at some point. Use Instruments to verify you don't have a real issue with memory.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason why you need to do this by hand? If you use a `UIImageView` and set the image either with `initWithImage:` or with the `image` property and then change `UIImageView`'s frame the image will resize accordingly

Comment: The goal is to create a new PNG on disk that has a file size less than 1MB.

Comment: @rmaddy You are correct! I am taking an image from the camera and saving it to disk. May I should edit my post with this.

Comment: also using this method, the image is keeps it size, this leads to decreased performance and decreased image quality compared to an image in the size of the UIImageView