# UIImageView masking creates memory warnings

Tags: ios, uiimageview, calayer, masking, image-masking

I have 4 UIViews each view contains around 16 UIImageViews. 
And i am applying mask to all the UIImageViews through below code

```
-(void)setMask:(UIImage*)maskImage forImageView:(UIImageView*)imageView
{
    CALayer *mask = [[[CALayer alloc] init] autorelease];
    mask.contents = (id)[maskImage CGImage];
    mask.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768);
    imageView.layer.mask = mask;
    imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    return;
}
```

Is this right code for UIImageView masking ?

Each UIImageView is changes image through mask. But after changing images in more than 5 UIImageView "Receive memory warning."  appears and it crashes.
All the images are in 1024*768 resolutions , even mask images too.

Comment: I don't know if your maskimage is the problem or the actual images in your uiimageviews. Check this post and see if it helps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12773074/received-memory-warning-on-setimage

Answer (score 1):

Try with this "

> UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions

But I'm not sure this will help you or not . but  I have been using it for many of situations , I didn't get any  of warning from it . Try It may be helpful .
  Something like this :

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageView.bounds.size, NO, 1.0); //retina res
[self.imageView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
[imageView.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 703, 294)];
[maskImages.image drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(10, 10) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:0.2];

UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
```

Answer (score -1):

You have ever use  creating mask using CGContextClipToMask i think it will work and will not give you memory warnings. You are using so many imageview. hows it's performance in retina? is it work in that with all that masking.

Comment: Sorry Amrit , it is also not working through that i have already done that. Thanks by the way.