# UIImage takes a lot of memory when loaded from file

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, memory-warning

In my iPad app at one moment I load 100 images from Photo Stream using ALAsset and following code:

```
  ALAsset *asset = [assets objectAtIndex:[sender tag]];
  ALAssetRepresentation *representation = [asset defaultRepresentation];
  UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:[representation fullScreenImage]
                                                     scale:1.0f
                                               orientation:0];
```

And everything works perfectly. But when I cache it to the file system as JPEG files, and then load them again with `UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:fullPath]`, application crashes with Memory Warning, and I can see in the profiler that it really uses a lot of RAM.
Why is this happening?

Comment: Use @autorelease to release the memory in a loop.

Comment: Similar to below code : 

  - (void)useALoadOfNumbers {
    for (int j = 0; j < 10000; ++j) {
        @autoreleasepool {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) {
                NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithInt:(i+j)];
                NSLog(@"number = %p", number);
            }
        }
    }
}

Comment: I am trying this right now. I have tried to use it in different place, and it didn't work out.

Comment: more info  :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9086913/objective-c-why-is-autorelease-autoreleasepool-still-needed-with-arc

Comment: Well, the problem there is that I don't have actual loop right there. I know about @autoreleasepool and trying to use it in different manner right now.

Comment: And it is still crashing with: Terminated due to Memory Error

Comment: can you post more code... Like .h and .m so that we can analyse it properly and give you the answer .

Comment: Images, when expanded as in a UIImage, take an *enormous* amount of storage.  If you *must* keep an in-storage copy, keep a copy of the JPEG file as NSData, don't keep the UIImage.

Comment: @HotLicks Even if I am using them in UIImageViews? Because I not just loading the images, but displaying them as well.

Comment: When you go to display a given image, *then* you convert it to a UIImage, but only while it's on-screen.

Comment: well, They have to be all on screen at the same time. And it works perfectly, when I use ALAsset, and it crashes, when I load files from the file system.

Comment: @flybirdx This may help. Use UIImage+Resize category and shrink your pics down when showing preview - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12773074/received-memory-warning-on-setimage

Comment: I already use this category, but the problem is that this is not showing the preview of the image, i have to have them all in 2048X1526 size.

Comment: The most weird thing is that there is no problem using ALAsset, and this happens ONLY when I load from the files

Comment: The full-sized images won't even all fit on the screen at the same time.  For thumbnails use a resized image.

Comment: I am sorry, but this is really not applicable in my case. And it still leaves the question open - why uiimageview takes so much more memory if loaded from file.

Answer (score 1):

One thing,

When you are loading the image from gallery, why not store the `AssetURL`, instead of the `UIImage`; that should take less space and increase speed.

When you need to show, use the thumbnail representation, perhaps?

Comment: The problem is that I have to be able to open this images even if they were deleted from the Photo Stream

Comment: @flybirdx then you should make a database and copy all the images from assets library.

Comment: @pawan how do I do that?

Comment: @flybirdx you can use sqlite or core data for storing the image .

Comment: @pawan do you think it will be better for storing binary data?

Comment: yes , if you need to get these image even after they were deleted from photo album, then you must store it in your app. i must suggested to save the data in document directory, if you have some text or few images. but here you have lots of images, then storing them in core data or sqlite is good option.

Comment: Well, Will this solve my problem anyway? Because I don't have any problems storing image as JPEG file.

Comment: I think, with your requirement, Database(sqlite or Core) is a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it was my bad. I found the problem, and it comes out that I have memory problems in any case. `ALAsset` and `imageWithContentsOfFile` are working exactly the same.

Now I will try to find the way to reduce each image's size.